# Uniform convergence of $f_n\rightarrow f$ and limit of zeroes to $f_n$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having some doubts on a homework question:

Let $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on compact subsets of an open connected set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$, where $f_n$ is analytic, and $f$ is not identically equal to zero.

(a) Show that if $f(w)=0$ then we can write $w=\lim z_n$, where $f_n(z_n)=0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.

(b) Does this result hold if we only assume $\Omega$ to be open?

I'm not too sure how to do (a)-- I think I might be able to do it just by using the definition of uniform convergence and the fact that $f_n$ has a zero at $z_n$, but this doesn't use the assumption that $f_n$ is analytic or that $\Omega$ is connected. I'm also guessing that the result doesn't hold if we only assume $\Omega$ to be open and not connected for obvious topological reasons, but not knowing exactly how to do (a), I'm not sure if I know how to prove this. Could anyone give me some pointers? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know $f_n$ has a zero at $z_n$? You should be able to come up with a counterexample to $(b)$ before you prove $(a)$: taking two connected components for $\Omega, f=0$ on one of them, and $f=1$ on the other, there are some readily available $f_n$ that would contradict the statement.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: To see that Kevin is right, consider $\Omega=B(0,1)\cup B(2,1)$, $f_n(z)=\begin{cases}\frac1n&z\in B(0,1)\\1&z\in B(2,1)\end{cases}$ and hence $f(z)=\begin{cases}0&z\in B(0,1)\\1&z\in B(2,1)\end{cases}$. The $f_n$ don't have any zeroes at all.

Comment: Dear Hagen, you are absolutely right: I'll delete the relevant comments (and present my apologies) . Of course, the correct hypothesis is that $f$ is not identically zero in any connected component of $\Omega$. I appreciate the irony that your counter-example is a modification of the one I give in my answer:-)

Comment: Thanks everyone, your comments were very helpful. I ended up using Rouché's theorem to prove the result.

Comment: Just to remark that analyticity is important: Take $f(z)=|z|^2$ and $f_n(z)=|z|^2+1/n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a small circle around $w$.
Then by Rouché's theorem $f_n$ has a zero $z_n$ inside the circle  for $n$ large enough (and maybe several if $w$ is a multiple zero of $f$).
Now shrink the circle and repeat: you will obtain the  convergent  sequence $(z_n)$.

By the way, this sketch of proof shows why  we must assume that    $f$ is not identically zero near $w$:  if  $f\equiv 0$  just take $f_n=\frac {1}{n}$  (which has no zero at all!) to get a counter-example.